# Как найти какой скрипт отдает сообщение на веб сервере? (lua скрипты)

Tags: кэширование, lua, httpd

Исходные данные такие.
Есть контейнер с Apache2 сервером и lua скриптами.
Захожу в контейнер, делаю:

```
grep -r "Invalid Layer" / 2>/dev/null
```

В ответ получаю:

```
/home/oe2/onearth/src/modules/time_service/time_service.lua: returnValue = {err_msg = "Invalid Layer 2"}
/home/oe2/onearth/src/modules/time_service/time_service.lua: err_msg = "Invalid Layer 3"
```

"Invalid Layer 2" и "Invalid Layer 3" это исправленные мной строки. В оригинале там было "Invalid Layer".
Далее делаю к веб серверу запрос, а в ответ получаю: "Invalid Layer" (обмен смотрю wireshark-ом).
[image: wireshark]

Далее предполагаю, что скрипы где-то закэшированы.
В соответствии с https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_lua.html кладу рядом с каждым скриптом файл .htaccess с содержимым:

```
LuaCodeCache never
```

httpd рестартую. docker контейнер тоже растартовал.
Не помогает.

Как дальше искать откуда вылезает "Invalid Layer"? Кто его генерит? С lua раньше не сталкивался.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось lua скрипты нужно было перекомпильнуть.

```
cd /home/oe2/onearth/src/modules/time_service/
luarocks make
```